# Substituting $t_0$ in Wronskian to solve 2nd order non homogeneous ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Hey everyone I need some help understanding how to use Lagrange method and specifically the Wronskian used in it to solve 2nd order non homogeneous ode.
 Let :

$$y''(t)+a_1y'(t)+a_2y(t)=f(t)$$

I know that the general solution to a non homogeneous 2nd order ode is:

$$y(t)=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)+y_p(t)$$

Where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two linear independant solutions of the homogenous ode and $y_p$ is a particular solution of the non homogeneous ode.

I also know that we can find $y_p$ using the Wronskian in the formula:

$$y_p=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{y_1(s)y_2(t)-y_1(t)y_2(s)}{W_{(y_1,y_2)}(s)}f(s)ds$$

Here's where I'm confused:

I'm not sure what $t_0$ should be... I think that any $t_0 \in I$, where $I$ is the interval for which the two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are continuous will do but I'm still not sure how to choose the value to substitute to $t_0$.

For example for the ode: $y''-y'-2y=e^{-t}$ I found that two linear independant solutions of the homogeneous are $y_1=e^{-t}$ and $y_2=e^{2t}$ and the particular solution should be:

$y_p=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{y_1(s)y_2(t)-y_1(t)y_2(s)}{W_{(y_1,y_2)}(s)}f(s)ds$

The Wronskian is $W(s)=3e^s $ so

$y_p=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{e^{-s}e^{2t}-e^{-t}e^{2s}}{3e^s}e^{-s}ds$

I could go on to integrate the function but I'm not sure what I should substitute $t_0$ with.. My books solution suggests $t_0=0$ but why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be carefull at last line it should be $$y_p=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{e^{-s}e^{2t}-e^{-t}e^{2s}}{3e^s}\color{red}{e^{-s}}ds$$ It's a function of s not a function of t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y_p=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{e^{-s}e^{2t}-e^{-t}e^{2s}}{3e^s}e^{-s}ds$$
$$y_p=\frac 13e^{2t}\int_{t_0}^t {e^{-s}ds-\frac 13e^{-t}\int_{t_0}^t }ds$$
At $t_0$ the function in the integrand becomes a constant. At $t$ you get a function of t. I don't know if I am clear. You should evaluate the integral at $t_0=0$ as suggested by your book and also at different values to see what happens. You end with the same answer because the homogeneous solution will absorb the extra terms of the particular solution.

$$y_p=\frac 13e^{2t}\int_{t_0}^t {e^{-s}ds-\frac 13e^{-t}\int_{t_0}^t }ds$$
$$y_p=-\frac 13e^{2t}|e^{-s}|_{t_0}^t -\frac 13e^{-t}|s|_{t_0}^t $$
$$y_p=-\frac 13e^{2t}(e^{-t}-e^{t_0})-\frac 13e^{-t}(t-{t_0}) $$
$$y_p=-\frac 13e^{2t}(e^{-t}-e^{t_0})-\frac 13e^{-t}(t-{t_0}) $$
The first term is absorbed byt the homogeneous solution. It remains only the following term:
$$\boxed {y_p=-\frac 13e^{-t}t}$$
The rest are extra terms as you can check...

Comment: So if the value of $t_0$ doesn't matter why not use indefinite integral?

Comment: Of course you can use indefinite integral too @SlimJim

Comment: Well sorry if I seem ignorant but is there any advantage in using definite integral?

Comment: We are all ignorant.. Well I don't see any advantage for the particular solution to use definite integral. But maube in some physics application it may be usefull. In this case it changes nothing.  @SlimJim

Comment: You made a mistake in your last formula....That's chy i couldnt find the answer....It should be $f(s)$ but you wrote $f(t)$ @SlimJim

Comment: Thank you very much @Isham !!

Comment: You are welcomed @SlimJim I added some lines with the final result for the particular solution...